# Check box in knockout simplegrid

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using the Knockout simplegrid. Once of my properties in my json object that is bound to it is a boolean. It is currently shown in the grid as "True" or "False".

What I need is a check box which will allow the user to click (which in turn fires a command to the server).

Is this possible with SimpleGrid?

Comment: Have you found any answer for this yet? If you have working fiddle for it then please post as i too need it.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to use a checkbox bind to the checked attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: yourproperty" name="yourproperty">
```

to call the function back to the server, you'll probably want to bind an ajax function to the change of the checkbox

eg

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: yourproperty, event:{change: yourfunction}" name="yourproperty">
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how do do this with the simplegrid?

Comment: Apologies I misread the question - as far as I know you would need to switch to a templated grid in order to display a checkbox

Answer (score 1):

For now I have (still learning how knockout bindings work):

```
                    <tbody data-bind=\"foreach: itemsOnCurrentPage\">\
                       <tr data-bind=\"foreach: $parent.columns\">\
                            <!-- ko if: ($parent[rowText] == 'false' || $parent[rowText] == 'true') -->\
                              <td><input type=\"checkbox\" data-bind=\"checked: $parent[rowText] == 'false' ? false : true\"/></td>\
                            <!-- /ko -->\
                            <!-- ko ifnot: ($parent[rowText] == 'false' || $parent[rowText] == 'true') -->\
                              <td data-bind=\"text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText] \"></td>\
                            <!-- /ko -->\
                        </tr>\
                    </tbody>\
```

Comment: Do you have any fiddle for this? I really need this too. I didnt understood what you mean in this condition <!-- ko ifnot: ($parent[rowText] == 'false' ||